# How to insert extra text in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, insert

I just want to add some extra text on top of input posted from a form as per the example below:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (Username) VALUES('$username')");
```

But I want the value into the table as:'username*text'
That is if user input a username as 'john', I want to get it entered into the table as 'john*text'.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) ."*text";
```

Do escape the user's input to avoid [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: PDO would also help here in avoiding SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
$username = $_POST['username'].'*text';//hence you get *text postfix to every value

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (Username) VALUES('$username')");
```

now check your result,it will definitely work.